# Java - get unix epoch with microsecond

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, java-time, date

I am struggling to get the unix time epoch with microseconds in this format(1586420933.453254). I tried different classes.

```
- java.utils.Calendar
- java.time.Instant
- org.joda.time.DateTime
```

But I am getting only milliseconds like this - 1586420933453

How do I get the unix epoch with microseconds like this 1586420933.453254 in Java.

Comment: See the documentation for `Instant` and the relevant methods on `System`. If `Instant` isn't providing that resolution, the system clock may not have it. Specify your runtime platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do it using standard java time Instant + a number format. Keep in mind the result will be in UTC, though. Here is a draft with current time:

```java
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.time.Instant;


Instant datetime = Instant.now();

// Extract needed information: date time as seconds + fraction of that second
long secondsFromEpoch = datetime.getEpochSecond();
int nanoFromBeginningOfSecond = datetime.getNano();
double nanoAsFraction = datetime.getNano()/1e9;

// Now, let's put that as text
double epochSecondUTCPlusNano = secondsFromEpoch + nanoAsFraction;
NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
format.setMinimumFractionDigits(6);
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(6);
format.setGroupingUsed(false);
System.out.print(format.format(epochSecondUTCPlusNano));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got this "1586426623.416" value. But it is not getting microsecond value.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. *.416* is the fraction of second, therefore the microsecond value. If you need **exactly** 6 fraction digits, you can add a line of configuration for the number format: `format.setMinimumFractionDigits(6)`.